# How can you easily test the save restore methods in android

Tags: android, testing

I know that if you have to test the onrestoreinstance() the system must kill previously the application. Is there any easy way to test that? I mean not going to open tons of other applications for the system to kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your AndroidManifest.xml does not block Activity's kill-restore on device rotations, then you can just rotate the device (or emulate device rotation if on emulator).

There is also another cool tool - on the emulator by default you should have 'Dev Tools' app installed. Open it and go to 'Development Settings', then check the 'Don't keep activities' checkbox. Since this moment the activities will be killed by OS as soon as they become invisible (in the background). So pressing 'Home' button will cause a kill for your activity. Then on the home screen pressing your app icon will restore your activity.

Comment: Ok both answers work! But from my point of view this seems more practical.

Answer (score 0):

You could open your app then kill in the via the home menu.

1. Device menu
2. Applications sub menu
3. Manage Applications
4. Find application and kill it.

That should help ya out.